# Why is my bash script that executes another script not exiting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm calling another script from my bash script like so -- with an ampersand.

```
OtherScriptThatDoesNotExit &
echo "done"
```

I see it getting to "done" but I still see my original script running is ps. Any idea why this could be? (Note, I'm running on Puppy Linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is still waiting on the subprocess you spawned. Use `nohup`, `disown` or `screen` to leave a long running task in the background and get back to your shell.

Comment: Additionally, if you *do* need to wait for the script to finish, you can use 'wait' to pause execution until all jobs have completed.

Comment: So I just call disown in the line after OtherScriptThatDoesNotExit? Or what are the differences?

Comment: Yes, though `nohup` is a bit more appropriate for script usage. `nohup` will redirect output to a file, with `disown` it'll be gone